# PSTricks equivalent to TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

Is there a way to make the grid in `\psgrid` look the same as the one in the `tikzpicture`?

```
\documentclass[12pt,pstricks]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\begin{document}
 \psset{unit=0.5cm}
 \begin{pspicture}(12,14)
  \psgrid[gridcolor=red,subgridcolor=green,gridlabels=0](0,0)(10,12)
  \psaxes[Dx=2,Dy=4,showorigin=false]{->}(0,0)(0,0)(11,13)
  \psplot{0.5}{9.5}{36 x mul sin 5 mul 6 add}
 \end{pspicture}\\\vspace{1cm}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \draw [ultra thick,<->] (0,13) -- (0,0) -- (11,0);
    \foreach \y in {2,4,...,12}{\draw [color=red] (0,\y) -- (10,\y);}
    \foreach \x in {2,4,...,10}{\draw [color=red] (\x,12) -- (\x,0) node [below,color=black] {\x};}
    \foreach \y in {1,3,...,11}{\draw [color=green] (0,\y) -- (10,\y);}
    \foreach \y in {4,8,12}{\draw (0,\y) node [left] {\y};}
    \foreach \x in {0.5,1,1.5,2.5,3,3.5,4.5,5,5.5,6.5,7,7.5,8.5,9,9.5}{\draw [color=green] (\x,0) -- (\x,12);}
    \draw [domain=0.5:9.5,samples=100,thick,<->] plot (\x,{5*sin(36*\x)+6});
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can also be done by `\psaxes` instead of `\psgrid`. It needs two calls of `\psaxes` in fact of the two different label distance.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\begin{document}

    \psset{unit=0.5cm}
    \begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(12,14)
    \psaxes[Dx=2,Dy=4,showorigin=false,ticksize=0,]{->}(0,0)(11,13)% without ticks
    \psaxes[Dy=2,Dx=2,showorigin=false,labels=none,%  with ticks
      yticksize=0 10,xticksize=0 12,tickcolor=red,
      subticksize=1,ysubticks=2,xsubticks=4,subtickcolor=green,](0,0)(10,12)
    \psplot[algebraic,arrows=<->]{0.5}{9.5}{5*sin(Pi/5*x)+6}
    \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I particularly like the easy function naming and the fact that you included the arrows.

Comment: As I play with this code further it really does do what I want and offers more flexibility because it is easier to understand therefore manipulate to do other grids.

Answer (score 5):

This is the Ti*k*z plot:

[image]

Here is a PStricks version:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=0.5cm}
\begin{pspicture}(12,14)
  \psgrid[gridcolor=red,subgridcolor=green,gridlabels=0,subgriddiv=4,gridwidth=.4pt,unit=2](0,0)(5,6)
  \psaxes[Dx=2,Dy=4,showorigin=false]{->}(0,0)(0,0)(11,13)
  \psplot{0.5}{9.5}{36 x mul sin 5 mul 6 add}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Note the use of `subgriddiv=4`, `gridwidth=.4pt` (default is `.8pt`) and `unit=2`. The last key-value stretches the grid out (twice as far), so we only need to go to coordinate `(5,6)` instead of `(10,12)`.

Comment: The grid is drawn at the PostScript level and assumes an equal layout in both x and y directions. If you insist on having a different `subgriddiv` for x and y, then one would have to rewrite the/add to/ create a new `Grid` function in [`pstricks.pro`](http://texnik.dante.de/dvips/pstricks/pstricks.pro). Alternatively, draw the grid manually...